# Two or more Get method in one Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, getter

Hi I have two Get method in one Controller as follows:

```
public class aController : ApiController
{
   public pubResponse GetPub(string a, double b, double c, string d)
   {
   }


   public pubResponse GetFeatures(string a, double b, double c, string d)
   {
   }
}
```

Both the method's signature are same except there is one more parameter added in the second one.

Question is how should I get the Controller to map the number of parameters passed and choose the action accordingly. If there are 3 parameters then Controller should GetPub and if 4 parameters then the Controller should GetFeatures.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? I'm assuming you didn't mean to have 4 parameters in GetPub.

public pubResponse GetPub(string a, double b, double c)
{
}

public pubResponse GetPub(string a, double b, double c, string d)
{
}

Or if both methods do the same thing you could make your 4th parameter string d = "" - an optional parameter - and only use it if it is not empty.